# Overload member access operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading

Is there a way to overload member access operator in python? Example (as it can be a XY problem, I'll provide an example containing what I want to do):

```
class A:
    def __someOverload__(self, name, *args):
        if (name == "foo") print("HW!")
a = A()
a.foo()

>>> HW!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try overriding getattr:

```
class A:
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == "foo":
            return lambda: print("hi")


>>> a = A()
>>> a.foo()
hi
```

A more complicated example:

```
class A:
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == "foo":
            return lambda *args: print(args)


>>> a = A()
>>> a.foo(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for to change the default behavior of Python's built-in functions. We only have to define the corresponding special method in our class.

```
class Purchase:
    def __init__(self, basket, buyer):
        self.basket = list(basket)
        self.buyer = buyer

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.basket)

purchase = Purchase(['pen', 'book', 'pencil'], 'Python')
print(len(purchase))
```

Here, the output is 3.
Hope this might helps:)

Comment: I'd like to change any call... 

Comment: Some of variations:[https://stackabuse.com/overloading-functions-and-operators-in-python/]

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) for this purpose:

```py
>>> class A:
>>>   def __init__(self):
>>>     setattr(self, 'foo', lambda: print('foo'))
>>> 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.foo()
foo
```